# Can't setup and execute golang migration using docker compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, dockerfile, golang-migrate

I can't get my Go app running. My goal is to run some migrations and then run the api server using a docker compose yaml file, so I'm using a db container for postgresql and a "back" container for the go service and the migration command so I can get everything up more simply. Here are the files:

Docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9
    ports: 
      - 4321:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=vet-app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
  back:
    build: ./vet-app-back
    ports:
      - 8080:4000
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_started
```

Dockerfile on /vet-app-back

```
FROM golang:1.19
WORKDIR /app
ENV VET_DB_DSN=postgres://postgres:admin@db:5432/vet-app?sslmode=disable
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . ./
RUN curl -L https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/releases/download/v4.14.1/migrate.linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xvz &&\ 
  mv migrate.linux-amd64 $GOPATH/bin/migrate 
RUN migrate -path=./migrations -database=$VET_DB_DSN up
CMD ["go run ./cmd/api"]
```

Results im getting on console after docker compose up:

```
 => ERROR [7/7] RUN migrate -path=./migrations -database=postgres://postgres:admin@db:5432/vet-app?sslmode=disable up                                     10.4s
------
 > [7/7] RUN migrate -path=./migrations -database=postgres://postgres:admin@db:5432/vet-app?sslmode=disable up:
#0 10.35 error: dial tcp: lookup db on 192.168.65.7:53: read udp 172.17.0.2:56570->192.168.65.7:53: i/o timeout
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c migrate -path=./migrations -database=$VET_DB_DSN up]: exit code: 1
```

It seems like it can't resolve "db". But I'm using "depends_on" correctly, in order to run Postgres first, so now I'm really stuck.

Comment: `depends_on` indicates a dependency when services are run; not when they are being built. Note that there may be an issue with your approach; consider what happens if your container is running, you make some changes and rebuild it (you now have the old code running but the migration has been applied to the database) - consider running the migration when the container is started. You may also want to consider a [health check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060375/11810946) (the fact the container is running does not mean that Postgres has begun accepting connections).

Comment: "consider running the migration when the container is started" this is the way.  You still need backwards compatible migrations unless you expect to take the old version(s) of the code *down* before migrating.  But container start-up is still the appropriate time to run migrations.

Comment: Hi @Brits do you mean running the migration on db container start or the "back" service?

Comment: No - the contents of the `dockerfile` are used to build the image (i.e. when you run `docker compose build`). You then run the image 1-many times with `docker compose up` (or `run`) - this executes the `CMD`. So I mean you should use something like `CMD ["sh", "-c", "migrate -path=./migrations -database=$VET_DB_DSN up && ./cmd/api"]. A, better in my opinion, option is to [embed the migration into the executable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71763079/11810946) (this way things are less likely to get out of sync).

Comment: Note that the above suggestion only applies if you want to run the migration every time the container starts. An alternate method is shown in the [read me](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate#docker-usage).

Answer (score 0):

A Dockerfile can never connect to another container.  You can never run migrations as part of your image build process, whether in Go or another language.

One good approach to this is to write a wrapper shell script that runs the migrations and does other first-time setup, and then runs a command it's given as arguments.  You can then make this script be your image's `ENTRYPOINT`.  For example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# docker-entrypoint

# run migrations as required
migrate -path=./migrations -database="$VET_DB_DSN" up

# run the command passed as arguments
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, make this script be your `ENTRYPOINT`; it *must* use JSON-array syntax.  There is also a syntax error in your `CMD`, which you're not seeing yet: the three words in the command need to be three separate JSON-array elements.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["go", "run", "./cmd/api"]
```

(I'd probably also move the `ENV` setting from the Dockerfile out to the Compose file, since the specific host name and credentials are specific to this Compose deployment; if you ran the image with a remote hosted database you'd need different settings.  Also consider using a multi-stage build to be able to run the program without needing the Go toolchain.  In this case you'd need to make sure the `migrate` tool and `./migrate` source directory are present in the final image.)